# Xcode repeatedly copying bundle resources

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a question regarding Xcode and bundle resource copy.

I'm currently working on a project with a large asset library. So, a clean install, or a change in a bundle resource warrants a copy of the "new" bundle resource(s).

However, the problem that I'm currently facing is that Xcode is copying a part of my entire asset library every single time that the application is built. This behavior is super weird, since on all the projects that I've worked, Xcode only copied resources if they had changed, or if it were a clean install, or if there was something new that had not been copied before.

In this case however, it copied all the resources on a clean install (expected). However, on every consecutive build, it is still copying some of the files over. Now this is super strange, since none of the files have changed, and it is not copying all the files, only a small portion of them. One more thing - if I run the same app, with the same configuration on the simulator, the copy DOES NOT happen (moar strangeness).

Is there some setting that I can change, or maybe a flag that I can include that might prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure it is actually copying them?  It will still *list* all of them as it completes the build, but it will go by very quickly because it is just checking if it needs to copy it (although the title is still "Copying").

Comment: is there anything in common about the files that are (supposedly) being repeatedly copied?

Comment: Hello folks. To answer borrrden's question: Yep. It is still copying them. Because when I run it on the simulator, the copy does NOT happen (super strange). To answer Michael Dautermann's question: Nothing in common. All the assets are in a single folder, and this is copying only a subset of the assets.

Comment: Nuke the build directory?

Comment: Hello. :) I'm not entirely sure I get the question - are you asking me whether I tried to nuke the build directory, suggesting that I do so, or asking whether that is the right way to go? Either ways, I did try nuking it, but that wouldn't help either. However, as stated in my answer, nuking it after using a one time script does help. :) Either ways, there will be a clean build for production, and this will certainly take us through dev much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a month since this question's been asked, and I've managed to find a "sort of workaround" solution.

Now, the reason I'm putting this in as the accepted answer is primarily because no other answer/solution has been posted as of writing this. If anything better is posted (or if I have an update), I'll be sure to mark a better answer as the accepted one.

Either ways, this "workaround" will work if you have a super large set of assets that don't change over consecutive builds.

The project I'm working on has a lot of audio and video files that have already been prepared, and aren't going to change (other than the occasional re-recording or something along those lines).

So, as my question states, Xcode was copying a subset of the resources. Ideally, once a resource has been copied (and there are no changes to it), it is not re-copied (at least not supposed to be re-copied) over consecutive builds. In my case, it was getting copied during every consecutive run, causing my total build to start time to be around 15 ~ 20 mins. I'd also like to point out that regardless of whether we used "run script" in the build phases or whether we had the media in our Xcode project, we were facing the same issue.

Solution:
What I did was I cleaned my project, deleted the app, and did a fresh install. So, the first time, it copies ALL the files over with the app. Also, the assets directory is **NOT** in my Xcode project. We've added a "run-script" phase, wherein we run **rsync** to copy the media from the media folder, over to the app, during every build.

Now, once the App has finished doing a fresh build; it would have copied over all the required media files.

Then, REMOVE/DISABLE the script, perform a Clean in Xcode (command + shift + K) and run the project again. This time, since there is no script being run, and since Xcode has performed a clean, wherein now it thinks that all it needs to do is re-compile the binaries, it builds super fast. Since I've **NOT** deleted the App, the media folder is still in my app, and my build to start times are now around 30 seconds ~ 1 minute (this includes sandboxing and code-signing). Code-sign and "sandboxing" the application still takes time, but this is waaaay better than having to wait 15 ~ 20 minutes every time I hit run. :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I've got very similar situation. Also, I have 6 000 resources in my app, and even listing some of them (not copying) was a bit slow. I've found another workaround (very similar to yours, but a bit easy to perform). It was inspired by your one, so thank you very much!

I copied the target of the project, set its bundle id as the original one (it was automatically set with ${PRODUCT_NAME} from build settings) and removed all the resources from Copy Bundle Resources section. First time (after removed from device app) I need to launch the original target with its resources, but then I can build the copied target while resources are still on device.

Some advantages:

- it's very easy to switch between both targets
- no need two write any scripts (that was purpose I did not use your solution)

Fun with numbers:

- 58 seconds from "Cmd+R" to loading screen appearing with bundle resource.
- 20 seconds for the same interval with empty "Copy Bundle Resources" section. Not so good as yours improvement, but still makes difference.

Hope this helps too :)

Comment: Oooo. That's actually a good idea as well! :)
I'll bear this in mind for future projects - so thank you as well! For the aforementioned project, we had the unique case of building 3 apps from the same source; the only difference between the 3 apps was the content. Some of the content was common and some of it was different, owing to which we had to use a script, to make management easier. :)